# Why isn't my item popping up in the creative inventory?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I'm trying to create an item. In `RP/textures/items`, I have its texture. I defined the texture in `RP/textures/item_texture.json`. In `BP/items` I defined its behaviors. I kept all these in the `development_resource_packs` and `development_behaviour_packs` folder respectively. When I load the game, it doesn't show the items in the creative inventory. It is something like an enchanted egg. I also made other enchanted eggs like turtle and dragon, but all of these never showed up. But all the recipes in `BP/recipes` are working fine (Except for the recipes for the enchanted eggs)

Here's the texture:[image: egg]

`item_texture.json`:

```
{
    "resource_pack_name": "Minecraft++",
    "texture_name": "atlas.items",
    "texture_data": {
        "egg": {
            "textures": [
                "textures/items/egg"
            ]
        },
        "diamond": {
            "textures": [
                "textures/items/diamond"
            ]
        },
        "turtle_egg": {
            "textures": [
                "textures/items/turtle_egg"
            ]
        },
        "dragon_egg": {
            "textures": [
                "textures/items/dragon_egg"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

`soul_egg.json`:

```
{
    "format_version": "1.16.100",
    "minecraft:item": {
        "description": {
            "identifier": "mpp:soul_egg",
            "category": "nature",
            "is_experimental": false
        },
        "components": {
            "minecraft:max_stack_size": 64,
            "minecraft:stacked_by_data": true,
            "minecraft:foil": true,
            "minecraft:icon": {
                "texture": "egg"
            },
            "minecraft:display_name": {
                "value": "item.mpp:soul_egg.name"
            },
            "minecraft:hover_text_color": "aqua"
        },
    }
}
```

Edit:
I changed the value under minecraft:display_name, because I added it to `en_US.lang` file

Answer (score 1):

The creative inventory thing hasn't worked for a long time and they haven't fixed that yet. It's super buggy and I think there may be some things that might work but it's super bugged and it probably isn't your fault.

Comment: Then how to obtain the item?

Comment: @JRBros the `/give` command. Optionally you could also make a Function that gives the player all the items in the addon (just a bunch of `give @s PREFIX:ID`s)

Comment: I tried it. it doesn't work